# WPF form displaying as winform

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-7, rendering

Sorry this is probably a really silly question but I am developing a WPF form on a Windows 7 machine with VS2010 yet when running the application the form still looks like a standard WinForms window.

I am assuming that it requires an extra component installed on the system to be displayed as shown in the designer?

PS: To be more specific what I am referring to is basically the outline and border.

[image: Designer]
[image: Running]

Comment: Do you have anything theme wise set up on your computer? If you don't have themes enabled, it might be downgrading the UI experience.

Comment: Just one of the standard windows themes. Just to be clearer Ill post a pic of what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, what you are experiencing is totally normal. Unless you have altered the default style of your controls, your application will be drawn using windows default look and feel.

Comment: Ohhhh, I guess it was silly of me to expect the form to look like it does in the designer. lol. Aggghhh Microsoft...

Comment: why does the designer show the form like that when it never gets displayed like that?

Answer (score 0):

That border is just for design purposes. But you could add your own Border to recreate it during runtime.